# How show void function in GUI (java)?

Tags: java

I have problem.
I have function

```
private double[][] tablica;
public void show() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= tablica.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= tablica.length[i]; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%7.2f ", tablica[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And now i would like to put it in GUI. I created button and text field

```
        myButton1 = new JButton("Show");
        myButton1.setBounds(160, 70, 250, 20);
        myButton1.addActionListener(this);
        add(myButton1);
        notepad = new JTextArea();
        notepad.setBounds(160, 100, 190, 200);
        notepad.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        add(notepad);
```

But now i dont know how i can show results of function `show` using this button.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {      
    if (e.getSource().equals(myButton1)) {
            notepad.setText()
    }
}
```

How should i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try to change the `show` method? otherwise I'm not sure if is possible ...

```
public String show() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i <= tablica.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= tablica.length[i]; j++) {
            result.append(String.format("%7.2f ", tablica[i][j]));
        }
        result.append("\n");
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Now you can use it as

```
notepad.setText(show());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     myButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
     {

         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
         {
            // ======your function====
         }

     });
```

Comment: If you don't update with explanation your answer keeps popping up at the "low quality review list". For now you get the :looks OK" but work on the explanation otherwise its via downvote back at review and might be deleted at all. Benefit of doubt just because its a second answer.

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I answered the question on stackoverflow, my English is not so good, I will pay attention next time